# Check to see if a FB page plugin/iFrame has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I'm trying to check if anywhere on my FB page plugin on my site has been clicked. Here is what my code looks like

```
                <div class="col-md-4 reset">
                <div id="facebook-feed" class="analytics-button">
                    <script>
                        (function(d, s, id) {
                            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                            js = d.createElement(s);
                            js.id = id;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=7735049693xxxxx";
                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                    </script>

                    <div id="fb-root"></div>

                    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/example" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false">
                        <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                            <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/example"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/example">example</a></blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried adding an onclick listener to "facebook-feed" but that doesn't register anything that is clicked in the fb iframe. Is there a way of having a div sitting on top of the iframe that won't affect users being able to interact with the iframe content? I don't want to find out what has been clicked or anything, just that the user is clicking on the fb iframe area. Is there any tips or tricks for achieving this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there even a way to just have an "invisible" clickable div sitting on top of the iframe?

Comment: if you put anything on top to bind listener to, the event won't pass to the target inside the iframe .. short answer is it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access events used with the **Facebook** via *[Event Subscription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5)*.

For example I was trying to listen to the *Page Like* (i.e. `edge.create`) event in the  *[Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)*. I was able to do it with the following code.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(){console.log('Page Liked!')});
```